# How can we be sure that liquid iron/titanium droplets can form around particulates on hot Jupiters - just as they do on Earth and Venus?

Tags: atmospheric-science, exoplanets

I know that we have some solar system analogs. But is there a limit to it?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the conditions involved in condensation seem laboratory-reproducible, so I would imagine these conclusions are on a pretty solid empirical base. Not my specialty, though.

What if we turn the question around- Why *wouldn't* liquid iron/titanium droplets form around particulates on hot Jupiters - just as they do on Earth and Venus?

Comment: Wow cool - do you have any links to condensation of other fluids on other particulates?